# How to make gradient with distortion in html and css?

Tags: html, css, gradient

I just search and did not find, I think i dont know what exactly this is ?

[image]

I know it have gradient but how to make those triangles ? Any helpful
link or code will be appreciated.

I currently doing

```
background-image:linear-gradient(red,white)
```

Comment: It looks like a background image.

Comment: @VasilisG. you know how to create them ?

Comment: It would be burdensome to do that using CSS. Try using a design program or image editing tool.

Comment: You could take a look at gradients, https://css-tricks.com/background-patterns-simplified-by-conic-gradients/  and a closer look at  https://css-tricks.com/background-patterns-simplified-by-conic-gradients/#bonus-intersecting-line-backgrounds